# git in a web development team using 1 remote dev server and no local dev environment

Tags: php, git, web, github

I'm working in a web agency with a small team (5 developers, 2 designers). We primarily work with PHP/MySQL web applications including Magento, Experession Engine and CakePHP. We use a combination of Windows 7 PC'S (developers) and Mac's on OSX (designers).

I've been looking into using github for our projects with 3 main goals:

1. To see who has edited files and allowing people to comment on files.
2. To avoid overwriting each others work as it's sometimes the case multiple people can try and work on the same file at the same time.
3. Allowing rollbacks to previous versions of a file.

This is our current workflow and I don't understand how github fits in with this at all. I realise that our workflow will need changing but I haven't been able to find a process which in any way seems to fit in with this:

1. All our work is done on a remote web server which is specifically for development (nothing "live" sits on here). The server is running Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc. Nobody has a local development environment set up on their machine and we don't want that if possible.
2. We all have FTP access to the development server mentioned above. We generally edit files directly on this dev server as it gives a very quick way to test things out (literally edit a file, upload it and run it in the browser). There are problems with conflicts, e.g. multiple people trying to edit the same file, which is why I'm looking into using git.
3. When everything has been approved on the development server it is made live by copying it to a different server. The live server can be anywhere - we use some servers we manage ourselves, sometimes we use third party hosting companies - it varies.

I've been looking into this for the last couple of days and all the approaches I'm finding seem impossible for us to use. Does anyone have any insight into the best way to achieve this? Or am I looking into something which isn't even applicable for the issues I'm trying to resolve?

I would appreciate any useful advice people can offer.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you already familiar with git and just want some general advice or are you new to git?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wouldn't you want local development environments on developer machines?

Comment: Git isn't going to solve multiple people working on the same file. It addresses multiple people working on **their own copy** of the same file, but if they're all FTPing in and editing directly it's still going to lead to overwrites.

Comment: Local development environments don't work for us. Consider Magento, which relies on a MySQL database. Our development servers firewall won't allow people to remotely connect to a database on there, and we don't want people running their own local copies of databases which will quickly become out of sync. Also there's the issue of setting up 7 different development machines which may have different configuration/paths - no thanks. The dev server we've got can store and run the scripts we work on so I don't feel that having local development environments is appropriate.

Comment: @AndyF That's what [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and [database migrations](https://github.com/antzhdanov/tigra) are for.

Comment: @ceejayooz external web services require public IPs for async answering. Just another example of requiring a remote dev box. Vagrant doesn't solve that. In fact, Vagrant is a "remote" development environment in much the same sense as what the original question is about - just much "closer" to your local machine than something in AWS for example but YACS (yet another configurable stack). But alas not publicly accessible. Yes this is important and yes it is a deal breaker in at least some development scenarios.

Comment: @ceejayoz using Vagrant with some type of database migration tool would work and would not require each instance of Vagrant to run on a public IP. The migrations could keep the database sctructures in sync as long as they are using git to sync their migration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a git repository at your testing machine and have every one of your team use git to push their changes to that repository. This way they will get notified, when their changes will conflict with those of other people.

A typical workflow could look like this:

1. Developer1 changes something at his machine.
2. Designer1 changes some files on his machine
3. Designer1 commits those changes to his local git repository
4. Developer1 commits those changes to his local git repository
5. Developer1 pushes his changes to the development machine.
6. Designer1 pushes his changes to the development machine

   1. in case of conflicts with the changes of Developer1 he will now be prompted what those conflicts are and will have to resolve them.
   2. Then the resolved changes will be pushed to the development machine.

This should fix your problem 1.) and 3.) and will make 2.) an explicit action, which means that your developers and designers will see what they are overriding. If changes happen at different parts of a file at the same time, than git may be able to keep both changes without needing further interaction.

But beware, that this still has the problem, that no one will get to test his own changes without interference of other people as those may change things at any time while someone is trying to test something. With only 1 development machine you can not prevent this from happening with git alone. As your team is rather small and your current approach doesn't fix this either it might be of little significance to you.

Comment: From the answers that have been given I think the issue is that our team would be *editing* files on their local machine but in order to run/preview their work it would have to go in /var/www/vhosts/dev.domain/httpdocs/ and this is the same directory for every developer (because they don't have local dev environments this is the only place they can run and preview their work). The above post sounds reasonable but I can't help but think it could still result in work being overwritten or "Designer1" working on an out-of-date copy of the files (unless he happens to pull after Developer1 pushes??)

Answer (score 1):

We have a very similar set up in the company I work. We actually have a different sandboxes on the dev server. In other words, we clone the repo into different sandboxes. Each developer/designer gets a sandbox. For example if there are 3 developers, there will be 3 sandbox directories + 1 staging directory

So, developer john gets /home/john/example.com and it can be viewed at john.example.hot (setting up vhosts)
mike gets /home/mike/example.com viewed at mike.example.com
tracy gets /home/tracy/example.com viewed at tracy.example.com
And there will be one additional staging directory. /home/staging/example.com staging.example.com

Staging merges all the changes together so it can be tested. All of these directories are accessible only with internal IPS.

We deploy these changes to production using RSYNC. More information here about RSYNC: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html

Comment: The difference for us is that our developers would be editing copies of files stored on their local machine. We don't have "home" directories set up on the web server for each developer. The approach you've given is what I found in a lot of other tutorials but I think this relies on users working/editing files in their own directory on the *same* development server. This isn't the case in our set up so unfortunately we can't use this.

Comment: Got you. Good luck with the set up.

Comment: @AndyF, I don't understand your response to this answer. You are asking for help with ideas for a good workflow because yours is now working wll. Then when a good idea is offered, you basically just say that you are not doing things that way. Of course you are not doing things that way, otherwise you would not need a new workflow. Why not setup a separate home directory for different users on the development system and point different web addresses to those? This would be a lot simpler than setting up a separate install of PHP, Apache, and MySQL on each developers computer.

Comment: Also, this works quite well with git. Each developer can ssh into the dev server with their own user account. Their can be a central bare git repository in the directory that hosts the official development version that combines everyone's work and is what you would end up releasing to the production server. Then for each user/developer, you clone that repository into their file system. Then they make changes to just their files and test it on their test URL. They can push to and pull from the central repository.

Comment: With this approach, you can still use SFTP (or FTP if that is what you prefer) to view and edit the files from your FTP program. It would also give you the option of running Vim or different terminal text editors directly on the server over a terminal if you SSH in.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 I posted the question nearly 2 years ago. In the end we didn't even bother using git at all. Unfortunately setting it up proved so complicated that the (perceived) benefits didn't justify the means. So we just gave up with it.

Comment: @AndyF “Never cruel or cowardly. Never give up, never give in.” - The Dr ;-) Maybe if you find yourself in this situation again, you will figure it out. Any good sysadmin would be able to set this up.